# deploy app do Delphi Alexandria para Android 33

Tags: android, delphi, deploy

Estou usando o Delphi Alexandria CE e queria fazer o deploy de um pequeno aplicativo para um celular com ANdroid 33, mas não consigo resolver o problema abaixo :

[PAClient Error] Error: E7176 Unable to execute '"C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-11.0.15.10-hotspot\bin\java.exe" -jar "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\22.0\CatalogRepository\AndroidSDK-2525-22.0.48361.3236\build-tools\33.0.3\apksigner.bat" sign --ks "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Roaming\Embarcadero\BDS\22.0\debug.keystore" --ks-pass pass:android --ks-key-alias "androiddebugkey" --key-pass pass:android "D:\Delphi\App_Calculadora\Android\Debug\Calc\bin\Calc.apk"' (Error 1)